# Custom filter for short and full name in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, ecmascript-6

I want to create a filter that could filter by short name and full name

I have done it by full name

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Indian Overseas Bank',
        'Housing Development Finance Corporation',
        'Industrial Credit and Investment Corporation of India',
        'Indian Bank',
        'City Bank',
        'City Union Bank',
        'Kotak Mahindra Bank',
        'Tamilnadu Mercantile Bank ',
        'State Bank Of India'
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

But I am not sure, how can I filter by short name like `IOB, HDFC, SBI`?

I want to the result to be like

```
Filter word     : Expected result 

IOB             : Indian Overseas Bank 
HDFC            : Housing Development Finance Corporation
SBI             : Stete Bank of India
ICICI           : Industrial Credit and Investment Corporation of India'
```

**Note :** Those banks are Indian banks. See, when I do filtering by  `SBI and ICICI` then filter won't recognize `of, and` words.

> Also if I am typing normal word like `india`, then I am expecting the results to be filtered by `india` same as I have done in the snippet . How could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you need a custom filter. Your job is to break words into abbreviations. Then you can simply match the model to your abbreviations as a normal filter would, I suggest `.indexOf()` method.

Here is my simple demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(inp, model) {
    if (!model) {
      return inp;
    }
    var ignore = ["of", "and", "Of", "And"];
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      var str = "";
      var arr = inp[i].split(" ");
      for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (ignore.indexOf(arr[j]) == -1) {
          str += arr[j][0];
        }
      }
      // str = str.toLowerCase();
      // model = model.toLowerCase();
      if (str.indexOf(model) != -1) {
        array.push(inp[i]);
      }
    }
    return array;
  };
});
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [
    'Indian Overseas Bank',
    'Housing Development Finance Corporation',
    'Industrial Credit and Investment Corporation of India',
    'Indian Bank',
    'City Bank',
    'City Union Bank',
    'Kotak Mahindra Bank',
    'Tamilnadu Mercantile Bank ',
    'State Bank Of India'
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

    <p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

    <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in names | myFilter:test">
        {{ x }}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

(The example is case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But what about SBI and ICICI.??? See my question again in  **Note** point

Comment: @RameshRajendran added that, simply ignore some keywords from a list by checking it with `indexOf()`